# Función para iniciar sesión utilizando hash en archivo TXT no logra cumplir condición

Tags: python, funciones, condiciones, hash

Tengo el siguiente código en Python para un script de "iniciar sesión", el cual te comprueba el usuario y la contraseña que le escribas en un archivo txt donde están los usuarios y las contraseñas escritas con un hash de sha512.

De momento solo está el usuario "luis" y la contraseña "luis" guardada con el hash.

```
import hashlib

usuari = input("Escriu el nom del teu usuari:")

contrasenya = input("Escriu la teva contrasenya: ")

contrasenya = hashlib.sha512(str(contrasenya).encode("utf-8") ).hexdigest()



archivo = open('usuaris.txt', 'r')

for x in archivo.readlines():

    if(usuari == x):
        print("L'usuari",usuari," es correcte es igual a",x)
    if(contrasenya == x):
        print("La Contrasenya ",contrasenya," es ccorrecte es igual a ",x)
archivo.close()
```

No entiendo el motivo, pero nunca entra en el if. Si cambio el "==" a un "! =" Para que entre sí son diferentes sí que entra, cuando son IGUALES (verificado haciendo un print).

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas aquí:

```
for x in archivo.readlines():

    if(usuari == x):
        print("L'usuari",usuari," es correcte es igual a",x)
    if(contrasenya == x):
        print("La Contrasenya ",contrasenya," es ccorrecte es igual a ",x)
archivo.close()
```

Primero, no está definido el contenido del archivo: ¿el usuario y su password vienen en la misma línea? ¿Separados por espacios, comas, otro?.

Dentro del ciclo `for`, la variable `x` es la línea completa leída, **incluyendo** el '\n' al final. Por tanto, `x` nunca será igual a `usuari` o a `contrasenya`.

Suponiendo que el archivo trae el usuario y la contraseña separados por espacios, la forma apropiada de validar es:

1. Leer la linea.
2. Separarla en sus componentes usuario y password.
3. Comparar.

El código es:

```
for linea in archivo.readlines():
    user, password = linea.strip().split(' ')
    if usuari == user:
        print("L'usuari", usuari, " es correcte es igual a", user)
    if contrasenya == password:
        print("La Contrasenya ", contrasenya, " es ccorrecte es igual a ", password)
```

No necesitas "()" alrededor de las expresiones lógicas en un `if`.

#### Demo

*Archivo usuarios.txt*

```
luis luis
raul zaskaui
sergio a9344
```

*Código*

```
usuari = "luis"
contrasenya = "luis"
archivo = "usuarios.txt"

archivo = open("usuarios.txt", "r")
for linea in archivo.readlines():
    user, password = linea.strip().split(' ')
    if (usuari == user):
        print("L'usuari", usuari, " es correcte es igual a", user)
    if (contrasenya == password):
        print("La Contrasenya ", contrasenya, " es ccorrecte es igual a ", password)
archivo.close()
```

produce:

```
L'usuari luis  es correcte es igual a luis
La Contrasenya  luis  es ccorrecte es igual a  luis

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he probado con la corrección que me dices pero me aparece este mensaje de error:  user, password = linea.split(' ')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)